# Embed Facebook profile into website

Tags: facebook, embed, profile

I've been searching, but can't get this to work. I am creating a site where users can register and include their Facebook username. I would like to embed their personal Facebook feed into the web site. Is this possible? If so, how?

I did find the code to include comments, but this isn't what I want to do. I want to be able to see their timeline on the web site.

Thanks in advance for the help
Darth Mikey D

Comment: Assuming the posts are **public**, you can make use of the [**Embed Comments Plugin**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-comments). If the posts are private, you would need to authenticate through Facebook and then make use of their API.

Comment: You can only get the users own posts. Not the newsfeed they see.

Comment: That's all I want is their posts. Just not sure how to do it. Obsidian, thanks for the reply, but that is just for embedding certain comments. I want to be able to see their posts on their timeline.

Comment: You’ll have to do that via API, have them login to your app and grant it the necessary permissions, and then read the data and display it. Will of course require review by Facebook, before your app can ask the necessary permissions from normal users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have a link to instructions on how to do this?